# How can I get customer details in Magento event checkout_cart_product_add_after?

Tags: php, events, magento

I'm making Magento event observer, but Magento site doesn't have very good documentation how events work or I jsut haven't found those documents. How can I get customer details in event checkout_cart_product_add_after?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the current customers information:

```
$customer_session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
```

If you want to know which methods you can then invoke on the object, you can use the

```
var_dump(get_class_methods($customer_session));
```

Example getting the name of the customer:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getName());
```

**PS:** Always make sure you check whether the customer is logged in:

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
  // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

may be this can help...

http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento_events_cheat_sheet/